# Hibernate: lazy collections and session.merge

Tags: java, hibernate

***What I have:***

I need to update my `entity`. I use Hibernatee conversation, that means that we already have `entity` in the session cache.

```
public void handle(Request request, Session session) {
  MyEntity updatedEntity = request.getEntity();
  session.merge(updatedEntity); //rewrite all lazy collections
}
```

So I send object to client, client full up the object and send it back for update.

***What the problem:***

**Lazy collections aren't sent to the client. As a result, if lazy collection hasn't been empty, than it will be overriden in `session.merge(updatedEntity)` string**

*It happens because client knows nothing about element in those collections*

***Question:***

How two merge `entity` in correct way? Means without rewriting lazy collections.

***EDIT:(how I work with my collections)***

```
public class MyEntity {
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id")
  private List<AnotherEntity> anotherEntities;


  public void setAnotherEntities(List<AnotherEntity> anotherEntities) {
    // we must work with the same instance of list (again, because of orphanRemoval)
    this.anotherEntities.clear();
    this.anotherEntities.addAll(anotherEntities);
  }
}
```

Comment: In your question you didn't show/describe us how do you work with collection. If you don't modify collection you must not have a problem with merge. If collection is modified specify please when and how do you do this.

Comment: @mvb13, do I unswer your question in EDIT section. If not - tell me please, you are welcome

Comment: Did you try to force initialization of the lazy collection before sending to the client with Hibernate.initialize(myEntity.getAnotherEntities()); ?

Comment: @mvb13, I don't want to send them to the client. Because it can be a collection of large files. Actually, for that reasoning I've made them lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `CascadeType.ALL` is the problem

You may use instead

```
 cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DELETE})
```

You may also add to this set any other cascade option you need.

Comment: As I unnderstand, you throw away `DETACH` and `MERGE` cascades. But as I understand, `MERGE` is used for deep object updating (instead of shallow). See http://www.coderanch.com/t/217882/ORM/databases/CascadeType-MERGE-good-explaination
@mvb13, please explain your decision. Wider is better

Comment: You should throw only merge(it disables cascade on merge). Otherwise when you merge objects(detached object has collection set to null). Hibernate rewrites object that is in persistent context with new one(form request). This causes the collection deletion. So once again you should throw CascadeType.Merge(by exchanging on some set of actions that you need). I showed only example for basic operations you may add other options you need.